# Why "Your question could not be submitted."

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am trying to submit a question. I have spent a lot of effort trying to be clear.

> I like to make icons containing text. They are 240x240 pixels.
>
> However, when I put them on my desktop, the icons are way to large and I have to resize them.
>
> Is there a way to make them display their true size?

But I keep getting

> Your question could not be submitted.

What could I do differently?

[image]

Comment: What's the issue it lists, and what's the rest of the question look like?

Comment: I added to my post. @Journeyman Geek

Comment: Dosen't it say what the issue is specifically? That seems rather broken if so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scroll down on that page. The "issue" would hopefully be highlighted in red. My guess would be that you need to add at least one tag?